# Find max length between parenthesis

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, substring

How can I find the maximum distance difference between `(` to `)` and `[` to `]` in a string with mixed parenthesis (Including open and close parenthesis).

For Example:

```
s = '()[(([]))]([[]])'

len_diff(s, '()') # -> 6 As s = 
                              # ()   [(([]))]   ([[]])
                              #       ^    ^    ^    ^

len_diff(s, '[]') # -> 8 As s = 
                              # ()   [(([]))]   ([[]])
                              #      ^      ^
```

Any type of nested parenthesis are allowed and Inputs are **Always Valid**.

Comment: The example is not very clear. Why are you not counting the `()` in the beginning of s? Are you only counting the number of '(' and ')' and not counting the square brackets when finding length for '()'? It would be better to give some more examples (perhaps with some explanation of the expected output)

Comment: I want to find the **maximum distance** between open  and close parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to use a stack. As you see an open parenthesis you push it into the stack and as you see a close parenthesis you pop the stack. As long as the stack is not empty, you keep counting the number of characters you are reading from the string. As soon as the stack becomes empty you can test if this was the biggest distance or not and update your `max_length` variable. Alternatively this can also be done through recursion as mentioned in the comment.

```
def len_diff(s, paren_type='()'):
    stack = []
    length = 0
    max_length = 0
    # Good to add checks here on length of paren_type
    open_paren = paren_type[0]
    close_paren = paren_type[1]

    for c in s:
        if c == open_paren:
            stack.append(c)
        elif c == close_paren:
            stack.pop()
        if len(stack) == 0:
            if length > max_length:
                max_length = length + 1
            length = 0  # reset the counter for next paren
        else:
            # we only want to start counting after seeing at least
            # one open paren, i.e. when the stack is not empty
            length += 1

    return max_length
```